# Cordova android black splashscreen

Tags: android, cordova, splash-screen

I'm launching a vanilla cordova android app with the following config.xml yet the launching screen on the android device is 3 seconds black, then the app shows up. How do I get splash.png to be the image that shows up as a splash screen for 3 seconds?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.ambieye.shine" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Shine</name>
    <description>...</description>
    <author email="...@gmail.com" href="http://website.com">
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <icon src="www/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png" />

    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="app/www/images/splash.png" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />
    <splash src="app/www/images/splash.png" />
    <platform name="android">
        <hook type="before_build" src="hooks/ioscopywww.cmd" />
        <!-- you can use any density that exists in the Android project -->

        <splash src="app/www/images/splash.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
        <splash src="app/www/images/splash.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
        <splash src="app/www/images/splash.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
        <splash src="app/www/images/splash.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>
app/
        <splash src="app/www/images/splash.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
        <splash src="app/www/images/splash.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
        <splash src="app/www/images/splash.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
        <splash src="app/www/images/splash.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
    </platform>

    <platform name="ios">
        <hook type="before_build" src="hooks/ioscopywww.sh" />
        <!-- images are determined by width and height. The following are supported -->
        <splash src="app/www/images/splash.png" width="320" height="480"/>
        <splash src="app/www/images/splash.png" width="640" height="960"/>
        <splash src="app/www/images/splash.png" width="768" height="1024"/>
        <splash src="app/www/images/splash.png" width="1536" height="2048"/>
        <splash src="app/www/images/splash.png" width="1024" height="768"/>
        <splash src="app/www/images/splash.png" width="2048" height="1536"/>
        <splash src="app/www/images/splash.png" width="640" height="1136"/>
        <splash src="app/www/images/splash.png" width="750" height="1334"/>
        <splash src="app/www/images/splash.png" width="1242" height="2208"/>
        <splash src="app/www/images/splash.png" width="2208" height="1242"/>
    </platform>
</widget>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer was the evil `screen`:

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
```