# Cordova Splashscreen does not work with Intel XDK

Tags: android, cordova, splash-screen

I activated the splashscreen plugin, created 9patch files and inserted them into the assets. What is more, I added  this..

```
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
```

to my intelxdk.config.additions.xml file and use

```
navigator.splashscreen.hide();
```

in my onDeviceReady event.

The splashscreen does not show anyway, when I build the app with Crosswalk.
What am I doing wrong? It would be nice, if you could help me with that.

Thx in advance.

Comment: This answer helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28390970/cordova-android-black-splashscreen