# Ionic4 SplashScreen background is black

Tags: ionic4, background-color, splash-screen

I'm working with ionic4 and generated all of my resources correctly, this is a sample of my splash.png

[image]

and here you can see one of my generated resources

[image]

But when I run my app (ionic cordova run android) I'm getting a black background and the logo can be barely seen

[image]

The parameters on my config.xml are this

```
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
```

Already checked this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28390970/cordova-android-black-splashscreen) but the parameter has been there since the beginning, any idea on what I'm missing?

Comment: Change the image and check whether the issue exist. If the issue solved after changing the image , then you have to update your current splashscreen image.

Comment: thanks for the idea, I tried with other transparent png's and got the same result, so now I'm not using transparency just a plain image and it's working as intended, I guess is some kind of bug with png's but now I'm not willing to dive in

Comment: Ok. So the issue was related to Image . In Ionic SplashScreen you can make a lot of modifications.Please go throgh Ionic documentation for more details

Answer (score 2):

in splash-screen you can do that white or any color background image and generate resource again because splash-screen is plugin and that one is use a native functionality so that time background is black default and you can't change that.